# SQLite: Combine SELECT and DELETE in one statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to run two statements like so:

```
Select amount from db where ID=5
DELETE from db where ID=5
```

Currently I prepare and run two different statements. I wonder if there is a way to combine it in one statement.

Basically all I need to do is to get an amount column from the row before it is deleted.

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think you can. They cannot be made into a single change since the delete may delete the information you are trying to get. It would break database integrity.

Answer (score 14):

SQLite does not support this extension to standard SQL -- you do have to use both statements, SELECT first, DELETE next.  You can wrap them in a transaction, of course, (BEGIN and COMMIT statements before and after will guarantee that), to guarantee atomicity and consistency.

Comment: For anyone coming back after 2021, SQLite now does support this. See @gerardnico's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70592506/4247453

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to select rows and delete them in one pass, you can use the [returning](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html) clause in the [delete](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) statement.

For instance:

```sql
delete from myTable returning *
```

The [delete](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) statement has all select functionalities possible such as `with` and `where` that permits to select rows with any logic.

Comment: The question may be old, but this is the best answer in 2022.  This feature was added into SQLite in 2021.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your calling thread/process has a unique identifier (e.g. thread_id), I *think* a viable approach would be to add a flag (say, "handlerid") to your table, which is set to null on insert, and then do:

```
update db set handlerid = <my_thread_id> where handlerid is null;
select * from db where handlerid is not null and handlerid = <my_thread_id>;
delete from db where handlerid is not null and handlerid = <my_thread_id>;
```

Not sure how it would perform vs a transaction but can't think of any reason it would be materially worse (might even be better), and using this approach the code seems about as straightforward as you can get. unlike a transaction, it won't require you to loop in the case that a transaction fails, in order to be sure that all outstanding elements that were in the table at the time of the most recent SELECT got processed.

Answer (score 0):

It's late but for future visitor. In my case I did like below

**I want to delete that ID where amount = 5 so I did this**

```
public void selectAndDelete() {


        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            int i=db.delete(table_name, "ID = (select ID from table_name where amount = 5)", null);

            if(i>0)
            {
                    // I'm inserting here new record
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
```

> So, In your case you need to modify where condition like you want

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by separating the two statements with a semicolon, e.g. (using the .NET port of SQLite):

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=fie.db3"))
{
  conn.Open();

  using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
  {
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM fies; DELETE FROM fies WHERE id = 5;";
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
        Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: All this will do is execute one statement and then the other.  It does not make it atomic.  Another process could modify the database in between the SELECT and the DELETE.  The only way to guard against that is to wrap them in a transaction.

Comment: I have tried the combining statement (not transactionally) and run in the SQLite manager (an add-on to Firefox). This what i had:

"SELECT amount FROM table where id = 5; DELETE FROM fies WHERE id = 5;"

command exectued, row was deleted, but nothing was returned from the combined statetement

Comment: Forgot to add: this is for iPhone embedded SQLite - so this may be a difference with combine statements. Can it?

Comment: Leon: Yes, this could be a difference in implementations.  I tested it with SQLite.NET; it definitely returns the result of the SELECT there.

Comment: finnw: so wrap them in a transaction: conn.BeginTransaction().  Having a transaction doesn't stop you using a combined SQL statement.