# Does DROP after SELECT still yield data?

Tags: sql, database

Given a transaction like

```
SELECT * FROM t;
DROP TABLE t;
```

Is this valid at all? If yes, what is the result - an empty set, or the previous content of t?

I am particularly interested in the SQLite case, but since this question was apparently not asked before, it would be nice to have a look at various databases - and possibly the differences between their various implementation versions (e.g. mobile).

Comment: umm....huh? What would you expect to happen?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564242#comment1426745_1564288 - it does not always seem to work as expected (over there, DELETE is used instead of DROP).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the behavior of mixed DML and DDL within a single transaction is implementation-defined, according to SQL standards. Also, you're talking about SQLite, which isn't really a SQL platform. Turn off automatic commits, start a transaction, execute both those statements, and see what you get. Repeat after `commit;`, and repeat again after `rollback;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, "It depends." The most readable source I know of is from [Melton and Simon's book on SQL:1999](http://books.google.com/books?id=wyhXvU0Eyg0C&lpg=PA523&ots=MsXIMqHO7k&dq=mixing%20dml%20and%20ddl%20statements&pg=PA523#v=onepage&q=mixing%20dml%20and%20ddl%20statements&f=false).

[image: Excerpt from Melton and Simon's book]

For those who don't understand what the problem is, consider this partial transaction.

```
begin transaction; 
select * from t; 
drop table t;
```

Without testing in your favorite dbms, think about this.

- Should the client see *any* rows before executing `commit;`?
- Should the client see any rows *after* executing `commit;`?

Then think about how *other* concurrent queries "should" behave under various transaction isolation levels.

Answer (score 0):

First you will get all the records you asked from table t,

after that it will drop the table.

As easy as that, from top to bottom.

Comment: The question is tagged "SQL". Are you making the claim that all SQL platforms behave that way, or that only SQLite behaves that way?